# configure Druid to connect to Zookeeper on port 5181

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mapr, druid

I'm running a MapR cluster and want to do some timeseries analysis with [Druid](http://druid.io/). MapR uses a non-standard port for Zookeeper (port 5181 instead of the conventional port 2181).

When I start the Druid coordinator service, it attempts to connect on the conventional Zookeeper port and fails:

```
2015-03-03T17:46:49,614 INFO [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181.
2015-03-03T17:46:49,617 WARN [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

The [Druid documentation](http://druid.io/docs/latest/Configuration.html) shows that the Zookeeper host can be set via the `druid.zk.service.host` property in `config/_common/common.runtime.properties`. It does not specify a property to edit the Zookeeper port.

Is the Zookeeper port for Druid configurable? Or is it necessary to run an additional Zookeeper service if using Druid with MapR?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was to add the port to the hostnames in `config/_common/common.runtime.properties`:

```
 druid.zk.service.host=zkNode1:5181,zkNode2:5181,zkNode3:5181
```

Answer (score 0):

it is configurable, you can have something like

```
druid.zk.service.host=localhost:8080
```